# Convert SharePoint 2010 list template to PnP Provisioning template

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2010, list-template, pnp-provision

Is there a tool or at least a guideline on how to convert SharePoint 2010 list template to PnP Provisioning template?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not aware of a tool that will convert a SharePoint list template to a PnP provisioning template but you could create a PnP provisioning template from an existing list using [Export-PnPListToProvisioningTemplate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/export-pnplisttoprovisioningtemplate?view=sharepoint-ps).

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work with SharePoint 2010 (I've verified). As you can see in the link you've provided: `Applies to: SharePoint Server 2013, SharePoint Server 2016, SharePoint Server 2019, SharePoint Online`

Comment: You'll need to migrate the list to SharePoint Online or a newer version and then use the cmdlet. Presumably you are already in the process of migration to a newer version, since you're attempting to use the provisioning engine?

Comment: The question itself is regarding the migration. What other way of migration are you thinking of?

Comment: As mentioned above, you will need to migrate the list that you wish to create a template from to a newer version of SharePoint in order to use the Export-PnPListToProvisioningTemplate cmdlet

Comment: I'm not sure if you comprehend, but you're now answering my question "how to peel a banana?" with "you need to peel a banana in order to eat it".

Comment: It's not that difficult, migrate an existing list using the SharePoint Migration Tool to a newer version and then use the cmdlet to create a template from the list you've migrated. There is no tool (as far as I am aware) to convert a list template file to a PnP provisioning template. These are your options, short of either manually creating the file or creating your own tool.

Comment: Ok, "SharePoint Migration Tool" can be the answer to my previous question, thanks. Because the verb "migrate" alone was ambiguous.